# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'emoji'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot which does certain things when being reacted with emojis

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(ctx, reaction, user: discord.User = message.author):
    global global_emoji
    if reaction.emoji == global_emoji:
        print('Reacted successfully')
```

But I am getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'emoji'
```

EDIT: I solved it, just had to remove ctx parameter

Answer (score 2):

Event [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) takes two arguments: `reaction` and `user`

In your case, `reaction` argument that you passing is actually `user` argument, and your `ctx` argument is actually `reaction` argument.

`ctx: commands.Context` gets passed only as first argument only in commands

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(
    reaction: discord.Reaction, user: Union[discord.Member, discord.User]
):  # typehinting there will not be parsed by discord.py, as its parsed only in commands
    if reaction.emoji == global_emoji:
        print('Reacted successfully')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an attribute that doesn't exist in the specified class.
For example

```
class Member(object):
def bla(self):
    pass
```

The mentioned class has an attribute called "bla", if you'll try to write Member.bla() everything will work fine. But what you're trying to do, is to reach "bla2", which doesn't exist.
If you want to know the attribute list for an object try to use vars() for example

Comment: I understand that the attribute doesn't exist but I am just confused because I followed the tutorial